# 24xxx programmer tool fails: Mono library downgrade? Other options?

Tags: mono

I use KEEProg_24xxx_03c to control an EEPROM programmer through USB. This has worked great for years.

However, now it complains:

```
$ mono ./KEEProg_03c.exe
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v4.0.30319

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

It is very likely that I have upgraded `mono` since I used it last time.

It sounds as if `mono` does not support this old binary. I do not have the source code, so I cannot link that to a newer version.

`wine` starts the program, but USB access does not work ("About" complains: Device not found).

What are my options? Is there a GNU/Linux tool that can control my 24xxx? Can I downgrade `mono` or install the old library version?

KEEProg connects via USB. The USB device is detected as:

```
[1333363.114683] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[1333363.248418] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[1333363.248423] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[1333363.248426] usb 3-2: Product: FT232R USB UART
[1333363.248428] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[1333363.248430] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: A700f2Je
[1333363.250897] ftdi_sio 3-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[1333363.250948] usb 3-2: Detected FT232RL
[1333363.251171] usb 3-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

The device looks very much like this one (I cannot find any visual differences): https://sigma-shop.com/product/31/usb-24xxx-i2c-e-eprom-programmer-microchip-atmel.html

The code can be found here: https://info.kmtronic.com/software/KEEPROG/KEEProg_24xx/KEEProg_24xxx_03c.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need runtime v2.0.50727:

```
$ ikdasm KEEProg_03c.exe | head -n 2
// Metadata version: v2.0.50727
```

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508922/mono-on-macosx-the-runtime-version-supported-by-this-application-is-unavailab/33517383#33517383 suggests:

```
$ mono --runtime=2.0 ./KEEProg_03c.exe
```

which works.

Comment: please, can you select your answer as the solution?

Comment: I can in 47 hours.